# Are $M,N \subset G$ necessarily subgroups for their elements to commute, given that $x^{-1} M x = M$ and $x^{-1} N x = N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to solve the following problem.

> Let $G$ be a group. If $M, N \subset G$ are such that $x^{-1} M x = M$
>   and $x^{-1} N x = N$ for all $x \in G$ and $M \cap N = \{1\}$, prove
>   that $m n = n m$ for all $m \in M, n \in N$.

I have already proven it for the specific case in which $M, N$ are subgroups of $G$ (see proof below). However, I can't prove it without this hypothesis. I think $M, N$ must be subgroups for the result to hold, but I can't find a counterexample to show this as well.

Any help with a proof or counterexample is much appreciated.

---

Current proof outline:

> $$ (m \cdot n)\cdot (n  \cdot m)^{-1} = (m  \cdot n)\cdot (m^{-1}
>  \cdot  n^{-1})  =: k$$
>   $ k = (m \cdot  n \cdot  m^{-1})  \cdot n^{-1}
>  \in N$, because $(m \cdot  n \cdot  m^{-1}) \in N $ and $n^{-1} \in
>  N$ (and $N$ is subgroup).
>
> $ k = m \cdot  (n \cdot  m^{-1}  \cdot n^{-1}) \in M$, because $m \in
>  M $ and $(n \cdot  m^{-1}  \cdot n^{-1}) \in M$ (and $M$ is subgroup).
>
> So $k \in M \cap N = \{1\}$, which implies $k = 1$ and
>   $$ (m \cdot n)\cdot (n  \cdot m)^{-1} = 1 $$
>   $$ (m \cdot n)\cdot (n  \cdot m)^{-1}\cdot (n  \cdot m) = 1 \cdot (n  \cdot m) $$
>   $$ m \cdot n = n  \cdot m $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion doesn't hold when $M$ or $N$ is not a subgroup of $G$.
Here is a counterexample.

Let $M=\{e,(12),(13),(23)\}$ and $N=\{e, (123),(132)\}$ in $G=S_3$.
Then $x^{-1}Mx=M$ and $x^{-1}Nx=N$ for all $x\in G$
and $M\cap N=\{e\}$.
$M$ is not a subgroup of $G$ and $(123)(12)\neq (12)(123)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be the [dihedral group of order $8$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examples_of_groups#dihedral_group_of_order_8), with $b$ an element of order $2$ and $a$ an element of order $4$. For $x,y\in G$ let $x^y=y^{-1}xy$. By direct calculation we have:

$$\begin{array}{rcc}
x:&e&b&a&a^2&a^3&ab&a^2b&a^3b&\\ \hline
a^x:&a&a^3&a&a&a&a^3&a^3&a^3\\
b^x:&b&b&a^2b&b&a^2b&a^2b&b&a^2b
\end{array}$$

Let $M=\{1,a,a^3\}$ and $N=\{1,b,a^2b\}$; then $M$ and $N$ satisfy the stated conditions, but $ba=a^3b\ne ab$.

Comment: Both answers were right and appropriate, but as I have to choose one, I chose the first and simplest. Hope you don't mind. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Wheepy: You’re very welcome.